# Popout Modal FB likes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

May I know what the name of this function or is there any references to do the function similar to the image below. 
I would like to load this when the website is loaded. 
I found some  method is do using Modal Box but it seem to be not really proper. 
Or this is the only way to do it?
Please guide me from here.

[image: PoPoutBox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery onload function and put the relevant code for popup window.
(https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) or you can use `window.onload=Load().

There are many popup window jquery modals - http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html

I personally recommend you to use http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/ , I have tried that and it's cool.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
});
```

Hope you got the answer :)

Comment: Glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has it's own native Modal Popup window.

```
$("test").dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 140
    });
```

Should get you started.

INFO: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal